# How to pass a custom html tag in jQuery PrintArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the Jquery function `printarea` to print a part of my page (some columns of a table).

If I place the selector class in the two columns I need to print, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="printarea">content1</td>
  <td class="printarea">content2</td>
  <td>content3</td>
</tr>
```

The function will print each column in one row:

`content 1
content 2`

If I place the selector class to the `tr` instead, like this:

`<tr class="printarea">`

It prints every column in one single row:

`content 1 content 2 content 3`

What I need is to print the two first columns in one row:

`content 1 content 2`

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: we didn't understand please explain clearly?

Comment: I only need to print the two columns in one row. Now it prints the columns in many rows.

Comment: please add your jQuery code which you are using for print.

Comment: I think you will find your life easier if you declare which elements you DON'T want to print, rather than the one you do. example: `<td class="noprint">content3</td>`. Because you want it to print the row, just not that column

Answer (score 1):

First of all hide all the rows in the table then show only two columns in the row using `:lt` selector in jquery. it displays first two columns in the below context

```
$("table tr td").hide();
$("table tr td:lt(2)").show();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wxvo8to/)

Answer (score 1):

This will work, Use Colgroups, don't need to use jquery, Is there a specific reason you want JS/Jquery ?

```css
.printable{background-color:red;}
.notprintable{background-color:yellow;}
@media print{
  
  .notprintable{display:none}
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" class="printable">
    <col class="notprintable">
   </colgroup>
  <thead><tr><th>print 1 head</th><th>print 2 head</th><th>none print head</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td> print</td><td>print</td><td> no print</td></tr><tr><td> print</td><td>print</td><td> no print</td></tr><tr><td> print</td><td>print</td><td> no print</td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td> print</td><td>print</td><td> no print</td></tr></tfoot></table>
```